# Emacs Org-mode: Quickly mark TODO as DONE

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'd like to have a shortcut to change the state of a `TODO` straight to `DONE` (and back) with the `CLOSED` time tag folded when I'm at any position on the line (not like speed-keys requiring to be before the first asterisk).

Currently I have 2 options:

1. <kbd>C-c C-t d</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd> (with `org-use-fast-todo-selection` set to `t`, <kbd>d</kbd> is my `DONE` state shortcut and <kbd>TAB</kbd> hides the subtree), **or**
2. <kbd>S-right</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd> (using `org-shiftright`, `DONE` is the first state after `TODO`).

Can you please help me bind this to a single shortcut like <kbd>C-c C-d</kbd>. Please note I have more states than `TODO` and `DONE` but this shortcut should just toggle between those too.

**Bonus points**: Additional command that also starts a new `TODO` item on the next line at the same level as the previous task.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have a look at [worf](http://abo-abo.github.io/worf/README.html).
`cwd` will change state to DONE, and `wta` will add a new TODO.

Comment: If you enable the "speed keys", then you'll have as well "t d" when in first column of a task.

Comment: You'd be better to use a `C-c <letter>` binding like `C-c d`, as all such bindings are reserved for end-users, whereas `C-c C-d` could end up clashing with something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "time tag", but based on the workflows you listed, the following command should do what you want:

```lisp
(defun org-toggle-todo-and-fold ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading t) ;; Make sure command works even if point is
                            ;; below target heading
    (cond ((looking-at "\*+ TODO")
           (org-todo "DONE")
           (hide-subtree))
          ((looking-at "\*+ DONE")
           (org-todo "TODO")
           (hide-subtree))
          (t (message "Can only toggle between TODO and DONE.")))))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-d") 'org-toggle-todo-and-fold)
```

---

As for inserting new `TODO` items on the same level as the current task, `org-mode` has built-in commands for this. You can read up on them by doing

- <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `org-insert-todo-heading` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `org-insert-todo-heading-respect-content` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: How about (org-back-to-heading t) instead of (beginning-of-line) to permit a wider range of locations where the proposed function can work?

Answer (score 4):

A simple toggle command could look like the following

```lisp
(defun my-org-todo-toggle ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((state (org-get-todo-state))
        post-command-hook)
    (if (string= state "TODO")
        (org-todo "DONE")
      (org-todo "TODO"))
    (run-hooks 'post-command-hook)
    (org-flag-subtree t)))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-d") 'my-org-todo-toggle)
```

The `post-command-hook` is a bit tricky, but is required since otherwise notes are added (and revealed) after the command, which makes the time log partially unfolded.

In order to start a new TODO item, you might have a look at the existing `org-insert-todo-heading` (bound to `<M-S-return>`)